# How do I get a ranked list of Ngrams with frequencies with scikit and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, scikit-learn

I am trying to this simple task with scikit but I am having trouble working with the sparse matrix.  For this, I don't care about document frequency.

This is what I have so far:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3))
n_grams = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.column_with_text)
```

At this point I know I am supposted to do something involving `n_grams` and `inverse_transform`, but I'm not sure what. I would like a list of [n_gram,frequency] ranked by frequency, like this:

```
"apple banana", 100
"this is fun", 100
"cool pandas", 99
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You get the vocabulary out of your vectoriser with `vocabulary_`; the values are the columns of the vectorized output corresponding to the keys:

```
vectorizer.vocabulary_
{'apple': 0,
 'apple banana': 1,
 'apple banana this': 2,
```

The frequencies will be the sums of the columns of `n_grams`, to calculate these it's probably easiest to convert the sparse matrix to a numpy array first with `toarray()`, then one way to match them up would be with a list comprehension:

```
vocab = vectorizer.vocabulary_
count_values = n_grams.toarray().sum(axis=0)
counts = sorted([(count_values[i],k) for k,i in vocab.items()], reverse=True)

counts
[(4, 'pandas'),
 (4, 'cool pandas'),
 (4, 'cool'),
 (2, 'this is fun'),
 (2, 'this is'),
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.  And I appreciate the explanation